# Unity get angle between origin and mouseclick

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, rotation, trigonometry

I'm attempting to get the angle difference between an origin (currently defined in '`worldPosition` coordinates) and a `mouseclick event` on a UI who's canvas is using `screenspace-camera`.

Previously, before I changed the setup of the UI canvas from 'worldspace', this was working fine. I'd click on a point on a circle, and the correct angle would be returned (`+/- 0.10f` which was acceptable).

However, as I continued to develop my UI, I found I needed to change the canvas setting to use screen space - `camera` (a different camera to the `main camera`). However now, there is unexpected, and unusual behaviour.

When I click on a point on the UI circle (say an angle of ~45 degrees to the right), this works fine. However should I click on a point lets say, ~210degrees to the right (or -150degrees whichever you prefer) it returns ~60degrees. if I click at ~180degrees, it returns ~68degrees etc....I cannot see a correlation.

Essentially, the angle returned is always within the +y and +x quadrant (top right `quadrant` if we turned the circle into a grid, with 0, 0 being the centre of the circle). I'm unsure as to why and cannot see the correlation.

Here is my code involved with getting the mouseclick location, and getting the angle;

```
public void YawPressed()
{
        Vector2 clickPosition = consoleCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 centerPosition = new Vector2(center.position.x, center.position.y);
        float angle = GetAngleBetweenVectors(centerPosition, clickPosition);
}

public float GetAngleBetweenVectors(Vector2 vector1, Vector2 vector2)
{
        Vector2 difference = vector2 - vector1;
        rawTargetAngle = Vector2.Angle(Vector2.up, vector2);
        float angle = rawTargetAngle;

        difference *= -1;


        if (difference.x < 0 && difference.y >= 0)
        {
            angle = 360 - rawTargetAngle;
        }
        else if (difference.x < 0 && difference.y <= 0)
        {
            angle = 360 - rawTargetAngle;
        }

        userTargetAngle = angle;
        Debug.Log("Angle: " + angle + " ---- Difference: " + difference + " ---- Raw: " + rawTargetAngle);
        return angle;
}
```

Comment: Try `ScreenToWorldPoint` instead of `ViewportToWorldPoint`

Comment: Ok so this system has worked....more or less....as in the object is rotating as intended (more or less, previously I had ~0.1 degree of inaccuracy, however now it is upward of 3-5degrees)....however to get it working, I had to add 6f to the x coordinate.....the y coordinate seems to go from +1 to -1 (which makes sense). however the x coordinate seemed to go from -7 to -5...which makes no sense to me (I have no idea why this is unless I have set something up incorrectly? My fix seems/feels dodgy and messy to me, is there a reason for this, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I've figured out (somewhat) the reason of needing to add 6 to the xcoord (its because of the pivot/center position of the parent object being offset by 6) so now I just add the centerX value instead of setting it manually. However I'm still unsure about the cause of the inaccuracies which are around 5degrees now. It works fine for 0.0 and 180.0, but it seems the closer you get to 90 and 270 degrees, the more inaccurate the angles become?